# Blender equivalent of zremesher?

Tags: topology

Does Blender have an equivalent of zBrush's zremesher tool?

I saw there was a nice retopology tool bsurfaces but it looks like you draw the wanted topology instead of generating it from a current mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is the [remesh modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) that can create a simple quad based mesh but it doesn't create a nice topology that follows the contours of the mesh like zremesher.

CGCookies [RetopoFlow](https://blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow) improves on the bsurfaces idea but you still manually draw the basis of the new topology.

Comment: Are there any plans of adding something similar to zremesher in the future?

Comment: @Animatoring - I doubt it. ZBrush's focus lies on modeling, while Blender is focused more on rendering and composition of scenes.

Comment: I can't recommend anyone to buy the RetopoFlow addon. For the issues it has the price is greedily high. Even on high end pc's and with a minimal amount of quads it starts lagging.

Answer (score 5):

There is a ZRemesher port for Blender available as a paid plugin, made by the original author of Zbrush's ZRemesher. Free demo version is available and you have a month to evaluate it yourself. As far as I tested it, it's a real deal, working quickly and resulting in a nice topology (for an automated tool).

https://exoside.com/quadremesher/

https://www.blendernation.com/2019/10/08/quad-remesher-auto-retopology-add-on-released-for-blender/

> The French software developer Exoside has released a Blender add-on version of their new Quad Remesher auto-retopology tool. Quad Remesher is based on the renowned ZRemesher in the ZBrush 3D sculpting suite, and comes from the same coder, Maxime Rouca.